# how to use IIF in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having  a problem with IIF()
here is my code  which gives me error

```
 sqla.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvestmentType", IIf(chkSelectAllInvType.Checked, 0, cmbinv.SelectedValue))

        sqla.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrokerCode", IIf(chkSelectAllMember.Checked, 0, cmbmember.SelectedValue))
```

I have two combobox and two checkboxes; checkboxes are named as `selectall` to select all the values from the combobox. 
The problem I am having is  that when I select both the select all checkboxes  it display the correct report, but when I select all from first combobox and select one item from 2nd combobox it is showing the report.  Similarly when I select one item from 1st combobox and one value from another combobox it is showing the report, 
but when I select one value from 1st combobox and select all from 2nd combobox it shows me a blank report.
Please guide me on where I am going wrong, or how do I make this correct?
I am also sharing the screenshot of my form so that you can have a good idea on that:

[image]

Comment: Manwhile you can use the [`If`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) instead of the old [`IIf` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx). It is strongly typed and allows short circuiting.

Comment: i am adding the value to my parameters in storeprocedure , so how to use if operator with this , can u please guide

Comment: To use the If operator just change IIF to If.  It sounds like the problem is in the stored proc, which we don't see.

Comment: didint work for me , please guide me how do i solve this , any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: You said: "Give me error". Please give us the exact error message.

Comment: i mean this shows me the blank report which is not corrent thts why i write it gives eror (shows blank report), apart i want the result

Comment: Then the query is not handling correct the value 0 for Investmenttype and brokercode. We need to see the SQL / Stored Procedure or whatever queries the data.